# Entity framework Core: How to get last committed relation state for nav. property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Let's assume there is a model

```
class Item{
   public int Id {get; set;}
}

class ItemHolder{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   ICollection<Item> Items {get; set;}
}
```

let's assume we have code like that:

```
var holder = new ItemHolder{Id = 123}
holder.Items.Add(new Item{Id=2});
holder.Items.Add(new Item{Id=5});
holder.Items.Add(new Item{Id=8});
db.Save(holder)
db.SaveContext();
```

after that, in some else scope we change this navigation properties like:

```
var holder = db.Holders.Single(i => i.Id = 123) // no navigation property load
holder.Items.Add(new Item{Id=3});
holder.Items.Add(new Item{Id=5});
holder.Items.Add(new Item{Id=7});
```

Now I want to load previously saved items to check - which of them still exists in the item, which items are newly added, which of them removed. I tried to use explicit loading with

```
db.Entry(holder).Collection(h => h.Items).Load()
```

but it's only add previously saved items to `holder.Items` without duplicates and any clearing, so after that it's no longer possible to understand which items was saved before, and which items added during current transaction. But I need to know that to manually set state for entities, like if they was saved before, but don't exists in current items - than it's `State.Deleted`, if it was in previously saved and still in current - it's `State.Unmodified`, if they wasn't in previously saved, but exist in current - it's `State.Added`.

*from example: 2,8 - deleted, 5 - unmodif, 3,7 - added*

So my problem is to get collection of previously saved items `holder.Items` in independent state from what field `holder.Items` contains currently. How to achieve that?

Comment: Is there any issue with retrieving the collection first and saving it locally before adding new items?